# Can't 'reattach' detached HEAD git

Tags: git, github, branch, git-detached-head

I had a branch `bug-fix` that was cut off of another branch `develop`

After merging my changes from `bug-fix` into `develop`, I deleted the branch through github, however I believe I was still checked into the branch when I deleted it.

I also had one untracked file in the branch `bug-fix`

After `bug-fix` was supposedly deleted I checked out out `develop` and saw `HEAD detached at develop`

**Here's everything I've tried to fix the detached head:**

1) First of all the branch `bug-fix` that was deleted and no longer appears on github still shows up when I run `git branch`
So I tried doing `git fetch` to update it. Still shows up

2) I checked out `bug-fix` and deleted the untracked file

3) I tried creating a new branch `temp` and then deleting it

Comment: Git itself won't normally let you delete the branch you're standing on, because that's too confusing. If this happened in some GUI, rather than on the command line, that means the GUI is broken. But in any case you should just be able to `git checkout` any *real* branch and you will no longer have a detached HEAD. Note that `git fetch` never deletes any of *your own* branches.

Answer (score 6):

If you saw the literal text string:

> ```
> HEAD detached at develop
> ```

(e.g., in `git status` output), this means that the name `develop` is *not a branch*.  (More precisely, it is not a *branch name*—the term "branch" is ambiguous, in Git.  See [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452))

For instance, in this Git repository for Git, if I run:

```
$ git checkout v2.10.0
Note: checking out 'v2.10.0'.
[snip]
HEAD is now at 6ebdac1... Git 2.10
$ git status
HEAD detached at v2.10.0
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

This is because the name `v2.10.0` is a *tag*, not a branch.

To get back onto `master` (which *is* a branch name) I just:

```
$ git checkout master
Previous HEAD position was 6ebdac1... Git 2.10
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
```

Branch names, in Git, are really not very important in the long run.  In the short run (while you're working) they *are* important and useful, but eventually a branch like `fix-bug-1234` or `test-new-feature` either works out, and gets incorporated into a long-lived development or release branch and hence gets deleted, or it turns out to be a failure and either gets deleted entirely, or gets "ignore merged" to terminate it as a dead end, and then has its name deleted.

#### What matters are the *commits*

In Git, the only thing that really matters are the commits themselves.

A branch name simply serves as a way to *find* commits.  The same is true of a tag name.  Each name lets Git find *one* commit—the name stores the big ugly hashes like `6ebdac1...`—and the commits themselves let Git find earlier commits.

The key difference between a *branch* name and a *tag* name is that a branch name is *supposed* to move, and in fact, will *automatically* move as you make new commits on the branch.  To that end, `git checkout branch-name` puts you "on" the branch, so that Git knows to *move* the branch when you run `git commit`.

Any other name, Git mostly treats as a name for the raw hash ID.  These give you a "detached HEAD".  For `git status` purposes, Git tries to remember the name you used to get into this "detached HEAD" state.  But it's the ID that really matters.

When you delete a branch name, the commits themselves stick around for a while—usually at least 30 days.  You can find their IDs in Git's "reflogs".  This is kind of a pain in the butt, because if you run `git reflog` you get a ton of stuff that is hard to search through.  But the commits are still in there.  You just have to find the one(s) you care about (use, e.g., `git show 08bb350` to see commit `08bb350`) and "resurrect" them:

```
$ git branch zombie 08bb350
```

for instance, if the commit you want back, as a branch, is `08bb350`.